# Containment of one convex hull in another

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, convex-optimization

This question is related my previous question ([Comparing two probability distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480998/comparing-two-probability-distributions)) which are both related to my current research.

Suppose we have two bounded convex hulls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the two sets of linear inequalities $A_1x \geq 0$ and $A_2x \geq 0$ and the common equality $\sum x=a$ where $A_1$, $A_2$ are real valued matrices, $a$ is a real positive constant and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. What conditions must be satisfied by $A_1$, $A_2$ for the first convex hull to be contained in the second convex hull?

Thank you.

Comment: $\{x: A x \ge 0\}$ can't be a bounded set unless it is $\{0\}$, because of homogeneity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. I forgot to include a equality constrain. I guess now it's bounded. Could you also please explain what you mean by homogeneity?

Comment: @MLT: *[Homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems)* basically means having zero on the right-hand side; then you can multiply the unknown $x$ by any scalar and still have a solution, so the set of solutions cannot be bounded unless the only solution is the zero vector.

Comment: It's not necessarily bounded unless you're assuming $x \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $\{x: A_1 x \ge 0, \sum x = a\}$ is nonempty.
For each row $R$ of $A_2$, you want every solution of $A_1 x \ge 0$, $\sum x = a$ to satisfy $R \cdot x \ge 0$, i.e. the optimal value of the linear programming 
problem P:

minimize $R \cdot x$ subject to $A_1 x \ge 0$, $\sum x = a$

is at least $0$.  The dual of this linear programming problem is D:

maximize $a z$
subject to $ A_1^T y + z {\bf 1} = R$, $y \ge 0$ (where $\bf 1$ is the vector of all $1$'s)

By duality, P has a solution with objective value $ < 0$ if and only if D
has no solution with objective value $\ge 0$.  Your condition is equivalent
to: there exist $y \ge 0$ and $z\ge 0$ such that $R = A_1^T y + z \bf 1$,
i.e. each row of $A_2$ is a linear combination with nonnegative coefficients
of $\bf 1$ and the rows of $A_1$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your explanation. I just have one question. In the first paragraph should it be "... satisfy $R\cdot x \geq 0$..." instead of $\leq$? thanks

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks.  I'll edit.